# Which .NET data provider for MySQL 5?

Tags: .net, mysql, dataprovider

I'm new to using MySql (I'm a SQL Server type of guy) and was wondering if the data provider version (most recent being 6.3.8 as per this page http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.0.html#downloads ) had anything to do with the MySQL server version I'm using (5.1.48-community)? Can I just go and download the latest data provider or do I need a specific version?

Thank you!

PS. As a side question, do you know any good visual management tool for MySQL databases creation and maintenance? In the style of the free SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql GUI tool for win32 .. .get it from here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

No, looks like recent is Net 6.4.4 ... you can get it here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: and it will work with MySQL 5.1.48-community (the one used by my hosting provider)?

Comment: Thank you. As a sidenote, I've seen that GUI tool is replaced by MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL Connector for .Net Version 6.4.4.
It works with 5.1.48-community.